# How can I output all network requests to pull a Docker image?

Tags: docker

In order to request access to a docker image on a public container registry from within a corporate network I need to obtain a list of all the URLs that will be requested during the pull. From what I can see, the initial call returns a json manifest and subsequent requests will be needed.

How can I get visibility of all the URLs requested when invoking `docker pull my-image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) docker uses is publicly available that clarifies each API call possible. What you should see is:

1. A GET to the /v2/ API to check authorization settings
2. A query to the auth server to get a token if using an external auth server
3. A GET for the image manifest
4. A GET for the image config
5. A series of GET requests, one for each layer

The digests for the config and each layer will change with each image pushed, so best to whitelist the entire repository path for GET requests.

Note that many will take a different approach to this, setting up a local registry that all nodes in the network can pull from, and pushes to update that registry are done from a controlled node that performs all the security checks before ingesting new images. This handles the security needs, controlling what enters the network, without needing to whitelist individual URLs to an external resource.